# Check if XML Document child node exists before parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to check if addresses child node delivery/invoice exist. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Here is the code for parsing the xml nodes which are in a dictionary (importlist).

```
if (fileref.importList.ContainsKey("Addresses")) //here I want to check if addresses child node deliveryaddress/invoiceaddress exist
{
var deliveryAddress = order.Elements(ns + "Addresses")
.Elements(ns + "Delivery")
.Select(e => new Invoices.Address
{
Name = (string)e.Element(ns + "Name") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Name"),
PostalCode = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalCode") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalCode"),
PostalArea = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalArea") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalArea"),
State = (string)e.Element(ns + "State") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "State"),
Street = (string)e.Element(ns + "Street") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Street"),
Country = (string)e.Element(ns + "Country") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Country"),
City = (string)e.Element(ns + "City") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "City"),

})
.Single();

var invoiceAddress = order.Elements(ns + "Addresses")
.Elements(ns + "Invoice")
.Select(e => new Invoices.Address
{

Name = (string)e.Element(ns + "Name") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Name"),
PostalCode = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalCode") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalCode"),
PostalArea = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalArea") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalArea"),
State = (string)e.Element(ns + "State") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "State"),
Street = (string)e.Element(ns + "Street") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Street"),
Country = (string)e.Element(ns + "Country") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Country"),
City = (string)e.Element(ns + "City") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "City"),

})
.Single();

Invoices.Addresses addresses = new Invoices.Addresses();
addresses.Delivery = deliveryAddress;
addresses.Invoice = invoiceAddress;
} //end of addresses check
```

Here is the XML doc example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoiceOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OrderId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">115</OrderId>
  <CustomerId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">21</CustomerId>
  <CustomerName xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">James Hertz</CustomerName>
  <Addresses xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <Delivery>
      <Street>11 Shewell Walk</Street>
      <State>CT</State>
      <PostalCode>CO1 1WG</PostalCode>
      <PostalArea />
      <Name />
      <City>Test</City>
      <Country>US</Country>
    </Delivery>
    <Invoice>
      <Street>11 Shewell Walk</Street>
      <State>CT</State>
      <PostalCode>CO1 1WG</PostalCode>
      <PostalArea />
      <Name />
      <City>Test</City>
      <Country>US</Country>
    </Invoice>
  </Addresses>
  <OrderStatus xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">Offer</OrderStatus>
  <DateOrdered xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">2015-06-15T14:00:00Z</DateOrdered>
  <PaymentTime xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">14</PaymentTime>
  <IncludeVAT xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices" />
  <OrderTotalIncVat xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">0.0000</OrderTotalIncVat>
  <OrderTotalVat xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">0.0000</OrderTotalVat>
  <Currency xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <Symbol>LOCAL</Symbol>
  </Currency>
  <TypeOfSaleId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">-100</TypeOfSaleId>
  <InvoiceRows xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <InvoiceRow />
  </InvoiceRows>
</InvoiceOrder>
```

Comment: I don't think this `(string)e.Element(ns + "Name") == null ? null : (string)e.Element(ns + "Name")` does what you think it does... This statement is syntactically equivalent to just `(string)e.Element(ns + "Name")`.

Comment: @RonBeyer: You *can* cast a null `XElement` value to `string`, and it will return `null`. So yes, the OP just needs `(string) e.Element(ns + "Name)"` and that will be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes you're right since string is nullable.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Well, the point is that that's the behaviour of the explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string`. (That *could* decide to throw an `ArgumentNullException`, but it doesn't.)

Comment: @JonSkeet How can it be an `XElement` if its `null`? I can see if the `e.Element(ns + "Name")` returns a value, but if it returns null, then its the behavior of the explicit conversion from null to string (which is just null), or am I really mistaking something here?

Comment: @RonBeyer: You're missing the fact that the compile-time type of the expression `e.Element(ns + "Name")` is `XElement` - therefore the cast to string is determined *at compile time* to be a call to the explicit `XElement` to `string` conversion. Think of it as just a call to `XElement.ConvertToString(e.Element(ns + "Name"))` but with extra syntactic sugar.

Comment: Try taking a look at ORM libraries. They should be able to map from XML / DB into your objects. After that, it's a simple check to see if the object's attributes are null or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check, you'd need to do a similar query of your XML to see if the element you are looking for exists, for example:

```
var addressesExists = order.Elements(ns + "Addresses").Any()
```

But, as you'd then execute this query again straight afterwards, you could just change your `Single` to `SingleOrDefault`.  This way, if it doesn't exist then the relevant address variable will be `null` (it will throw an exception if there is more than one address, though). In addition, as has been noted, your `null` checks are redundant and can be removed.

Tying this together, you delivery address query would be as follows:

```
var deliveryAddress = order.Elements(ns + "Addresses")
    .Elements(ns + "Delivery")
    .Select(e => new Invoices.Address
    {
        Name = (string)e.Element(ns + "Name"),
        PostalCode = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalCode"),
        PostalArea = (string)e.Element(ns + "PostalArea"),
        State = (string)e.Element(ns + "State"),
        Street = (string)e.Element(ns + "Street"),
        Country = (string)e.Element(ns + "Country"),
        City = (string)e.Element(ns + "City"),

    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will be `null` if there is no address on this path.